# Using log4j2, is it possible to assign a specific level to a appender?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, appender

Using log4j2, I would like to set the maximum level of persistence in mongodb, independently of logger level and global configuration level.

Note that `NoSql name="databaseAppender"` **level="info"** it's not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="30">

  <Appenders>
    <File name="log" fileName="target/test.log" append="false">
    </File>  
    <NoSql name="databaseAppender" level="info">     
      <MongoDb  databaseName="mydb" collectionName="log" server="127.0.0.1" port="28001"
                factoryClassName="MongoUtil"
                factoryMethodName="getMongoDB"/>
    </NoSql>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="log"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </Root>        
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a level on the appender-ref:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="log"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" level="info" />
    </Root>        
</Loggers>
```

If you want to do more complex things like *only* have INFO level messages (no TRACE/DEBUG, no WARN/ERROR/FATAL) go to a certain appender, then you can use a combination of multiple [threshold filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter).